# Would it be worth migrating a ruby install to RVM?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rvm

Several months ago, I installed ruby 1.9.1 on Mac OSX 10.6 using the instructions here, modified for the newer versions of ruby/rails/gem.

http://hivelogic.com/articles/compiling-ruby-rubygems-and-rails-on-snow-leopard/

A project has now come up where I need to develop a site using an older version of rails, and consequently, an older version of Ruby. I've successfully installed RVM, older versions of gem and the rails gems, but now I'm mildly worried about my environment. Technically, I have 3 groups of Ruby installs floating around - the native 1.8.7 that was included with OSX 10.6, my own 1.9.1 installed in /usr/local/, and 1.8.7 in RVM.

I'm concerned that this could cause strange, difficult to diagnose errors in the long run. Would it be worth the trouble of uninstalling my 1.9.1 /usr/local and/or the baked-in 1.8.7, and installing them in RVM?

Comment: MacOS installs Ruby in /usr/bin for its own purpose and Apple-supplied apps use it. You should consider yourself a guest if you use that instance, and tread lightly if you modify it. For development work install your own "private" instance of the Rubies you want to test against. Then you're free to mangle, fold and spindle them all day long without causing problems for the system.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All the Rubies you use for development should be under rvm (or rbenv, as John comments). It avoids the headaches you describe--nothing more exciting than having a surprising library pulled in.

While I *have* removed the system Ruby on some OS X machines and not been affected by it, the Tin Man's point about not removing it outright seems reasonable, and `rvm` makes it unnecessary to do so. Some tools, like `brew`, rely on having a Ruby available; if you *do* remove it, you'll need to make sure that everything the system Ruby had is still available to prevent breakage.

Comment: @JohnBeynon Yep, `rbenv` is nice too, and avoids some issues with `rvm`.

Comment: On MacOS, Ruby is pre-installed and owned by the OS for its own purposes. We can piggyback/abuse it but we shouldn't delete or move it, so using `rvm system` is the appropriate way to work with the System's instance. IMO opinion, disk space is cheap and adding an additional RVM controlled version of 1.8.7 is the best solution. At that point the OS can use its installed version all it wants, and we get to use our own installation.

Comment: @theTinMan That's a fair point, although I've yet to have an issue after having removed the system Ruby. YMMV.

Comment: You haven't noticed it. If you do a `find /usr -type f -name \*rb` you'll find Apple installed code that needs the system installed Ruby.

Comment: @theTinMan Like I said, *I* haven't had an issue related to removing it. But I'll modify the answer again.

Answer (score 2):

RVM also supports the use of its own and the system ruby interchangeably.  I've made use of that before, but I also agree with Dave, in that you should probably just move into the RVM world, it won't take much more effort and gives much in return.

`ryanmt@Hermes:~$ rvm use system

Now using system ruby.

ryanmt@Hermes:~$ rvm use default

Using /home/ryanmt/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290`

Answer (score 1):

I'd propose a halfway house - install the other rubies in RVM and test the apps running under those with the RVM rubies? If they work, then move completely over the RVM. If they don't, you haven't lost anything, just don't use RVM for those apps. You don't need to uninstall the originals to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Don't remove Apple's Ruby, but do install RVM. You probably should remove the one in `/usr/local`.